# Prompting for and Reading an XML File

Tags: xml, powershell

I think I've got what I need from the rest of the script I just need help with asking and reading the XML file and then piping it through the rest of the script. If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
param([string] $file)

try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host "File not found."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Please enter a file path."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Read-host to get the input from the user, with a loop to make sure the path exist, like this:

```
param([string] $file)

try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
} catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    Write-Host "File not found."
} catch {
    Do
    {
    $XMLFile = Read-Host "Please enter a file path"
    }
    until (Test-Path $XMLFile)
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $XMLFile)
}
```

Comment: Get : The term 'Get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Manage-Users.ps1:14 char:18
+     $xml = [xml](Get - Content XMLFile)
+                  ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get:String) [], ParentContainsE 
   rrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException